# How to create an importable module?

Tags: python, module, ode

I was following [this](https://hplgit.github.io/scipro-primer/slides/ode2/html/ode2-1.html) tutorial and after creating the classes I still cannot `import` the desired module. The code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
class ForwardEuler:
    def __init__(self, f):

        # test that f is a function
        if not callable(f):
            raise TypeError('f is %s, not a function' % type(f))
        self.f = f

    def set_initial_condition(self, U0):
        self.U0 = float(U0)

    def solve(self, time_points):
        """Compute u for t values in time_points list."""
        self.t = np.asarray(time_points)
        self.u = np.zeros(len(time_points))

        self.u[0] = self.U0

        for k in range(len(self.t)-1):
            self.k = k
            self.u[k+1] = self.advance()
        return self.u, self.t

    def advance(self):
        """Advance the solution one time step."""
        u, f, k, t = self.u, self.f, self.k, self.t

        dt = t[k+1] - t[k]
        unew = u[k] + dt*f(u[k], t[k])
        return unew

class ODESolver:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def advance(self):
        """Advance solution one time step."""
        raise NotImplementedError  # implement in subclass

    def set_initial_condition(self, U0):
        self.U0 = float(U0)

    def solve(self, time_points):
        self.t = np.asarray(time_points)
        self.u = np.zeros(len(self.t))
        # Assume that self.t[0] corresponds to self.U0
        self.u[0] = self.U0

        # Time loop
        for k in range(n-1):
            self.k = k
            self.u[k+1] = self.advance()
        return self.u, self.t

    def advance(self):
        raise NotImplemtedError # to be impl. in subclasses

class ForwardEuler(ODESolver):
    def advance(self):
        u, f, k, t = self.u, self.f, self.k, self.t

        dt = t[k+1] - t[k]
        unew = u[k] + dt*f(u[k], t)
        return unew
```

Now, I want `from ODESolver import ForwardEuler`, but there is no module named `ODESolver`. How do I create it? I suppose there must be something with `if __name__ == '__main__':` and then the classes underneath, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Most modules are just files in a directory somewhere. For test, you could create `testme.py` with a single line `print("hello world")` and it should import. The question is whether the python importer can find the file. Where is it in relation to the script where you do the import? (I assume this file is called "ODESolver.py").

Comment: Also, post the full traceback message. It tells us about that script that tried the import. I don't know why one would leave the python error message out of a question here on SO!

Comment: You should read the [python documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Also, to learn how to make a module, don't write hundreds of lines of code. Start with a module which has only one line, e.g. `a = 7`

Comment: @tdelaney it is "no module named ODESolver" if I type "from ODESolver import ForwardEuler".

Comment: Normally one gets a multiline traceback message (it literally starts with "Traceback (most recent call last):"). Perhaps you have an exception handler that filters that stuff out. Still, we need to know _how_ you run this code. Is it in a script, the shell, an IDE? Is the .py file in the same directory as the script? The importer needs to be able to find the file. It may be in the scripts current directory, or somewhere in the python path. `import sys;print(sys.path)` would show you the standard places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of the file.py where you are writting this code is the name of module
you must name it ODESolver
then you can do

```
from ODESolver import ForwardEuler
```

Comment: No, it needs a python extension to it, likely "ODESolver.py".

Comment: @tdelaney if you thinking about the module that you import that does not need the extension. If you thought about the file containing the code, my bad, that needs the .py extension. Make things clear!

Comment: create new file past your code in  the file must have name  ODESolver.py then save it  , module in python is just file.py  then you can do this import from an other file in the same project

Comment: Yes, I am thnking about your statement that the file should be named "ODESolver". That needs an extension (or it needs to be a package directory with other python modules in it).